# Goals do not match segment

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I've set up goals in Google Universal Analytics:

Destination: URL matches regex `/secure/common/callback.*?success\=true`

But when I look at a custom segment against the same data the numbers are way off.

Goals yesterday:
2,040. But if I go into the default reporting view "audience" and create a custom segment with the same regular expression the numbers are way off `/secure/common/callback.*?success\=true`

860 visitor from 630 unique visitors.

Conceivably, if a person orders more than once (highly unlikely)  visits could be higher but it's rare.

Anyway, goals suggest we had 2,040 goal completions. I know from looking at our database that we had less than half that.

Am I interpreting goals wrong here?

Comment: Hrmm strange. Try the regex: `/secure/common/callback.*\?success\=true`. And make sure you're looking at only conversions for that specific goal (not goal completions in total which is a sum of all goals).

Comment: @TomFuertes I actually also posted the question on a separate GA forum (on G+). Turns out that when viewing goals in GA>Conversions>Goals>Overview the metric is for unique page views of the conversion page (The regex). By comparing with the custom segment, I was looking at the default audience overview report. Page views there, and within a custom report, show all page views in a session where a person saw the conversion page. I checked this by drilling down into GA>Behavior>Content>Pages and then applying my regext - the numbers match!

Comment: Interesting! I thought goals were 1 / session; but I guess not!